# PHP5 webpage scan (simple DOM parser || file_get_contents()+regexp)... resources wise

Tags: php, regex, dom, web-crawler, file-get-contents

I was thinking about a script that would scan 10+ websites for specific content inside a specific `div`. Let's say it would be moderately used, some 400 searches a day.

Which of the two in the title would support better the load, take less resources and give better speeds:

Creating the DOM from each of the websites then iterating each for specific div id

**OR**

creating a string from the website with `file_get_contents`,
and then regexping the needed string.

To be more specific of what kind of operation I would need to execute hear the following,

Additional question:
Is regexp capable of searching the following occurrence
of the given string:

```
<div id="myId"> needed string </div>
```

to identify the tag with the given ID and return ONLY what is between tags?

**Please answer only yes/no, if it's possible, I'll open a separate question about syntax so it's not all bundled here.**

Comment: Basically what Artefacto said. But don't use the raw DOM methods. Try phpQuery (or maybe QueryPath), which has a nice API for extracting and scraping websites. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html

Comment: While I second the link suggested by @mario, I disagree to not using the DOM methods. DOM is great. Unless you want CSS Selectors there is no reason to use a third party lib.

Comment: @Gordon: Well I think `echo qp($url)->find("#myId")->text();` is a good enough reason for eschewing the complex API. But QueryPath is also supposedly more resilient against HTML errors.

Comment: @mario Not for me. I know a lot of people think DOM has a too verbose and awkward to use API but I never understood why. It clearly communicates what it does. And since it's language agnostic, I can use the same in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Speed will depend on your server and the pages in question; both ways execution time will be negligible comparing to the time of downloading the pages to scan.
3. if you go with DOM / XPath, the thing is doable in 3 lines of code.

Comment: Artefacto's and this answer should be both awarded as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For 400 searches a day, which method you use is rather indifferent, performance-wise.

In any case, the fastest method would be `file_get_contents`+ `strpos` + `substr`, unless your location+extraction algorithm is complex enough. Depending on the specific regular expression it may or may not be faster than DOM, but it likely is. DOM will probably be a more reliable method than regular expressions, but than depends on the level of well-formedness of your pages (libxml2 does not exactly mimic the browsers' parsing).

Comment: Actually pcre is most typically faster than Zend bytecode and handicrafted strpos/substr code.

Comment: @mario While function calls are expensive in PHP, we're talking about maybe two extra calls here vs compilation of a regular expression. In any case, I added a "save" clause.

Comment: ty for the specifics, great answer